# Como eu uso o entity generator do doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-2

Estou tentando usar o doctrine em um projeto. porém estou tendo dificuldade em conseguir usar o entity generator uma vez que o banco de dados está pronto e gostaria que o doctrine criasse as entidades a partir dele.

> bootstrap.php

```
<?php
// o Autoload é responsável por carregar as classes sem necessidade de incluí-las previamente
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

// o Doctrine utiliza namespaces em sua estrutura, por isto estes uses
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping;

//onde irão ficar as entidades do projeto? Defina o caminho aqui
$entidades = array("entity/");
$isDevMode = true;

// configurações de conexão. Coloque aqui os seus dados
$dbParams = array(
'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
'host'     => 'localhost',
'user'     => 'root',
'password' => 'senhadodb',
'dbname'   => 'LojaVirtual',
);

//setando as configurações definidas anteriormente
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($entidades, $isDevMode);

//criando o Entity Manager com base nas configurações de dev e banco de dados
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
```

Estou tentando criar as entities com o seguinte código:

```
$cmf = new Doctrine\ORM\Tools\DisconnectedClassMetadataFactory();
$cmf->setEntityManager($entityManager); // $em is EntityManager instance
$metadata = $cmf->getAllMetadata();
$generator = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\EntityGenerator();
$generator->setGenerateAnnotations(true);
$generator->setGenerateStubMethods(true);
$generator->setRegenerateEntityIfExists(true);
$generator->setUpdateEntityIfExists(false);
$generator->generate($metadata, 'entity');
```

Também já tentei com esse:

```
$classes = $entityManager->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();
$generator = new EntityGenerator();
$generator->setGenerateAnnotations(true);
$generator->setGenerateStubMethods(true);
$generator->setRegenerateEntityIfExists(false);
$generator->setUpdateEntityIfExists(true);
$generator->generate($classes, 'entity/');
```

Nunca trabalhei com doctrine antes, procurei na documentação e em varios sites e nada de encontrar uma forma de fazer isso funcionar. Achei alguns tutorias explicando para fazer por Command Line porém eles também não me foram úteis.

Espero que alguem possa me dizer o que está errado e/ou o que devo fazer para gerar as entidades a partir de um db pronto.

Comment: Qual problema você esta tendo?

Comment: Ele sempre da um erro relacionado a meta data, dizendo que não conseguiu carregar as metadatas validas ou algo do genero

Comment: Pode colar o erro para eu ter uma noção melhor? :)

Comment: sim sim, só estou esperando o composer instalar tudo de novo pra mim reproduzir o erro novamente

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti não consegui reproduzir o erro, agora a página só fica em branco sem retornar erro nenhum.

Comment: Aparece alguma coisa no log de erros? Tentou colocar o procedimento dentro de um bloco try/catch e ver se dá alguma exception?

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti tem alguma sugestão de tutorial pra mim seguir e fazer o entity generator? acho que vou fechar essa pergunta, já fiz quase todo o mapeamento manualmente mesmo

Comment: Não precisa fechar, vamos deixar a pergunta aberta para que outras pessoas que têm o mesmo erro consigam resolver.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19317/discussion-between-rodrigoborth-and-rodrigo-rigotti).